# Stop Angular 12 from replacing space characters with &nbsp;

Tags: angular

How do I stop Angular 12 from replacing the space character with `&nbsp;`?  It's causing issues with line breaks, as `&nbsp;` is obviously the non-breaking space character.

For example, when I render my component the string `"This is an example string."` has been replaced with `"This&nbsp;is&nbsp;an&nbsp;example&nbsp;string."`

Here is my component application-card.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Application } from 'src/app/services/apps.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-application-card',
  templateUrl: './application-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./application-card.component.css']
})
export class ApplicationCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() application: Application;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this outputs "This is an example string." as expected
    console.log(this.application.description);
  }

}
```

The 'application' object is passed to the component by:

```
      <app-application-card *ngFor="let application of getApplicationsFiltered()" [application]="application"></app-application-card>
```

application-card.component.html:

```
<div class="app-card-body">
  {{application.description}}
</div>
```

^ This is where I expect to see `"<div class="app-card-body">This is an example string.</div>"` but instead get  `"<div class="app-card-body">This&nbsp;is&nbsp;an&nbsp;example&nbsp;string.</div>`"

Definition of application:

```
 export interface Application {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  image: string;
  suggested: boolean;
  active: boolean;
  url: string;
  helpdesk_url: string;
}
```

I'm not sure how to stop this behaviour.   I would like {{application.description}} to emit `"This is an example string."` without the `&nbsp;` control characters being inserted.  Any assistance understanding how to stop this behaviour would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What browser is this happening in?

Comment: Google Chrome 93, Microsoft Edge 93 and Mozilla Firefox 91

Comment: Where is this application object coming from? Could you reproduce this in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) maybe? This way we can more easily help you.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7, I created a Stackblitz and sure enough, didn't reproduce.  I've now worked out this is nothing really to do with Angular, for some reason the C# Web Server (Kestral) is re-writing "This is an example string." as "This\u00A0is\u00A0an\u00A0example\u00A0string." in its JSON serialiser output, even through the input string 100% just a normal space.   \u00A0 is of course, non-break space character, so Angular is doing exactly what it should.    Sorry for the wild goose chase and thank you for your help.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 - and it was your comment "Where is this application object coming from?" that made me think to look very hard at the JSON output, so thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Create Pipe: `replace-spaces.pipe.ts`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'replacespaces' })
export class ReplaceSpacesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return value.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
  }
}
```

Declare `ReplaceSpacesPipe` in the module where `ApplicationCardComponent` is declared

```
declarations: [ApplicationCardComponent, ReplaceSpacesPipe]
```

And in template:

```
<div class="app-card-body">
  {{application.description | replacespaces}}
</div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gxthor?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)